# Adaptive expectations

Tags: macroeconomics, monetary-policy

I know expected inflation plays a key role in both the Phillips curve equation and the Fisher equation, but does it also play a key role in Taylor's Monetary Policy Rule?

I'm asking this as I have an assignment question which requires me to derive the DAD curve, with a different expected inflation, and I am unsure if I have to change the expected inflation in the monetary policy rule as well.

Answer (score 1):

Important details are missing, but just think: *whose* expectations about inflation are included in the monetary policy rule? Model consistency should help you answer your question.

If you provide more details on your model, I will be happy to expand.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the Fed's (nominal) policy rate depends on the *real interest rate*, which is the difference between the nominal interest rate and the *expected* inflation, as you noted from the Fisher equation.

For example, suppose the Fed's policy rate is set at 8%. On one hand, suppose that people expect prices to rise at 1%, then the real interest rate is 7%. This implies a very tight monetary policy. On the other hand, if expected inflation is very high at 7%, then the policy rate at 8% is quite accommodative. This is why monetary policy rules have to account for inflation expectation.